# Angular 2 event emitter

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase

I got this class :

```
export class Project {
  $key: string;
  file: File;
  name: string;
  title: string;
  cat: string;
  url: string;
  progress: number;
  createdAt: Date = new Date();

  constructor(file: File) {
    this.file = file;
  }
}
```

I have upload component where I upload all of this information to my database/storage and it works fine.

Then I am showing all of the Projects in home.component like this :

**Upload.Service :**

```
 getUploads() {
    this.uploads = this.db.list(`profile/${this.auth.userId}/project`).snapshotChanges().map((actions) => {
      return actions.map((a) => {
        const data = a.payload.val();
        this.showVisualContent(data.url, data.name);
        const $key = a.payload.key;
        const $ref = a.payload.ref;
        return { $key, ...data, $ref };
      });
    });
    return this.uploads;
  }
```

**Home.Component :**

```
 uploads: Observable<Project[]>;

ngOnInit() {
    this.uploads = this.navSrv.getUploads();
    }
```

**Home.html :**

```
 <div *ngFor="let project of uploads | async" class="responsive-width">
  <mat-card-title class="project-card-title">{{project.name}}</mat-card-title>
</div>
```

In this way I am showing all projects in home.component. What I want is :

- I click on one of the projects in my home.component.
- Go to child component
- See only clicked project information (not all projects).

**I know just a little about event emitters (maybe I need to use them), but I don't really know how to get that project on which I click and show it in child component.** How To do that ?

```
getOneProject() { //and pass it to another component

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need EventEmmiter for this type of problem. EventEmmiters are used when you want to send some data from Child Component to Parent Component, not the other way around.

As i understood, you want to click on  element and redirect to component with only that particular project data. For this type of solution, you will need to have a route (for example  /projectComponent) and when you click on  you get redirected (using routerLink) to that route with project data like in this example:

```
<div *ngFor="let project of uploads | async" class="responsive-width">
    <mat-card-title class="project-card-title" [routerLink]="['./projectComponent', project]"> {{project.name}}</mat-card-title>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I think this answer is the closest one to my solution, but still when I click on mat-card I get redirected to projectComponent and there are all projects.

Comment: Yeah, i get what you want to do. You can than pass just an id to route, not whole project object. Like this [routerLink]="['./projectComponent', project.id]" and then when your projectComponent initialize, you can get data like this this.projectId= this.route.snapshot.data['id']; and make an api call to get just the project with that id, or you don't have to make an api call , you just need to filter data from getUploads() function and get project with obtained id.

Comment: [routerLink]="['./projectComponent', project.$key]" - will not work, because I need to write it in my router module as I understood.

Comment: Write it in router module? Please clarify this.

Comment: Sorry, When I go to : www.url.com/-468468468 (project key) , I get blank page and it's normal, if I want to get this.project I need to get it from database first now with it's key ? or there is another way ? How to show that project now in that component ?

Comment: If you think that you will need to make a new route with id placeholder, than yes. Something like this:   {
    path: 'projectComponent/:id',
    component: ProjectComponent
  }

Comment: Sorry, When I go to : www.url.com/-468468468 (project key) , I get blank page and it's normal, if I want to get this.project I need to get it from database first now with it's key ? or there is another way ? How to show that project now in that component ?

Comment: Ok, you are getting an id which is great, now you have 2 options: first, make an API endpoint that recieves id and returns project object, when you get that object, just render it in component. Second solution is, when you first call this.uploads = this.navSrv.getUploads();
    } , cache those uploads somewhere to be globally availible (in your session storage or local storage) and then when you have id of wanted project , just go through that cached array of projects and find the one with the same id

Comment: After you get that project , just render it in your html template. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Can I just take that KEY and render that database object with that key from my firebase db  ? I just dont know how to get that key

Comment: Yeah Andrius. This is the example of getting KEY or id from your url route:  let projectId = this.activeRouter.snapshot.params['id']; Put this line in constructor of ProjectComponent. This will get id from route. Again, it is important that in your router module you have route like this 'projectComponent/:id'  so that you can use this.activeRouter.snapshot.params['id']   ,   if you have 'projectComponent/:key'  you will have to have in your ProjectComponent  constructor  this.activeRouter.snapshot.params['key'].   You get the idea...

Comment: Ok one more question and I will do it I think : 

How do I definde this.activeRouter ? Because its undefined right now : activeRouter does not exist on projectComponent

Comment: Not a problem at all my man. :)   In your ProjectComponent you need to declare variable activeRouter: ActivatedRoute;  and import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';   This ActivatedRoute saves the route that you came from. Let's say that you were on www.url.com/homepage and then went to www.url.homepage/projects/225699,  than ActivatedRoute saves in memory that last url!

Comment: Glad i helped you

Comment: You can update to a full answer which will be better then this one. I think there are more people with more questions like me.

Comment: Agreed. Will do.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Project` component is a child of the `Home` component, you don't need an event emitter. Just use the `@Input()` decorator in the parent's template to pass all the data you require in the child. You can have a look at the [official Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) regarding passing data from parent to child with input binding.

Comment: If you could answer with the code example it would be nice and I would accept it as an answer,  because I can get all Projects, how to pass them to another component with Input Output decorators ? And not all, only on which I click.

Answer (score 0):

Events can't be passed down from a parent to a child, in your case; your better of using a service.

Essentially, you'll want to create a component out of your project and iterate through that, then set a click event in the html to call a function which sets some data in the service based on the clicked project.

Then all you'll need to do is pull that info down from the service into your child component.

I've sudo coded the main part of the solution:

```
export class projectHandlerService {
    public projectInfo: any;


    setProjectInfo(info: any) {
        this.projectInfo = info;
    }
}

@Component({//stuff here})
export class Project {
    $key: string;
    file: File;
    name: string;
    title: string;
    cat: string;
    url: string;
    progress: number;
    createdAt: Date = new Date();

    constructor(file: File, private projectHandler: projectHandlerService) {
      this.file = file;
    }

    onClick() {
        this.projectHandler.setProjectInfo(//whatever info you want to pass)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the `Project` (child) component should have an input property:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

...

export class ProjectComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input("project") project: Project;
  ...
}
```

And then your loop should bind to this input property in the Home component template:

```
<div *ngFor="let project of uploads | async" class="responsive-width">
  <mat-card-title class="project-card-title" [project]=project></mat-card-title>
</div>
```

This way you will be able to pass down the `project` property and render it in the child component.

In your specific case, you do not need to emit an event with an event emitter, because this is used in case you want to propagate data from the child component to its parent.